# Reverse columns and rows when exporting report to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Exporting an access form to an excel file.

I have code which basically works, but enters all data in one row, instead of one column.  Is this an easy fix?

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

If fd.Show Then
    Me.Filter = "[ID] = " & Me!ID
    Me.FilterOn = True
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "Checkride", "(*.xls)", fd.SelectedItems(1), True
    Me.FilterOn = False
End If
```

Separate question, based on the same code: If I simply enter a filename, this does not save the file as .xls file.  I can type filename.xls, and it works, but that is not optimal.  Is there something to change on the DoCmd line?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867331/access-2013-accde-file-cant-export-to-acformatxlsx) is worth reviewing for alternates to using `DoCnd.OutputTo`.

Comment: What about transpose?

Comment: Is there a way to use transpose while in Access?  It looks like an Excel function.